debug view of google analytics 4 stopped working on real devices and only works in the simulator
I have xcode version 16 and until recently I was able to successfully connect to debug view analytics of firebase to see my device connected there and the events.,
But suddenly I stop see my device connected,
Sometimes after a few hours I suddenly see my device in debug view.
I noticed that the simulator usually works well, although it is not 100%, but connects more times than the device.
What could be happening?
We checked on several internet networks, we removed and reinstalled the app, we refreshed and did everything necessary and there is no solution.
I tried reinstalling older versions of my project and that didn't help either.
I checked on several iOS versions.
